# Send messages from multiple smart watches to phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to send messages from multiple smart watches to the smart phone(android) using message api. In the latest update of google play services, multiple smart watches can be connected to a smart phone using capability api. Since there are very less tutorials out there, I am finding it difficult to set this up. Could anyone please help me with the steps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) for a good introduction and steps that you need to follow to set this up; first, your phone needs to advertise a certain capability that it has (say, it can transcribe voice messages) in an xml file. Then all other nodes on the wear network can query the framework for the nodes(s) that provide that capability and finally, each can send a message to those nodes. A good number of our samples on GitHub have been updated to use CapabilityApi (e.g. [android-DataLayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DataLayer) sample) so you can look at them and see how things are set up. Finally, you can use [WearCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary) that provides that functionality for you if you want or willing to use a library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked for 1 wearable to phone. Now I need add another wearable. Currently the project has 1 mobile and 1 wear folder. How do I add the second wear folder? Is there any specific way to do it? Is it like I will install the same wear files in different wearables by changing the capability name and other required changes?

Comment: I am facing one more issue. I have a samsung gear live and a new LG watch. Google api client is getting connected to the gear live watch. But I am getting version error for google play services for LG watch. How can I fix this? Please help

Comment: The number of watches is not important; every watch should look for the very same capability and since your phone app is the only one that provides that capability, all connected watches should be able to find your phone.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Currently I have paired gear live to my phone using Android wear app. Now how do I connect my second wearable? Can I use it without pairing? I am also getting play services version problem for my second wearable. Could you please help?

Comment: You can pair multiple watches to the same phone. When you do the pairing, it should get an update.

Comment: HI, could you please explain why sending message via message api is the fastest method? How is it able to send messages faster than bluetooth sockets?